# how to apply a different config to a secondary set of hosts

Tags: ansible

I have a redundant pair of hosts and I would like to apply a different config on them, but not sure how to do this.  My hosts are named hostA and hostB. I dont know how to read only the last character of the hostname and if A apply one config and if B apply a different config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to re-invent the wheel testing your hostname. You simply need to [organize your inventory and your vars correctly](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables)

A quick and dirty illustration.

## Directory structure

```
.
├── host_vars
│   ├── hostA.yml
│   └── hostB.yml
├── inventories
│   └── test
│       └── hosts.yml
└── playbook.yml
```

## `inventories/test/hosts.yml`

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    hostA:
    hostB:
```

## `host_vars/hostA.yml`

The file for hostB is similar with a different value

```
---
a_var_i_need: "var value for host A"
```

## `playbook.yml`

```
---
- name: demonstrate host_vars usage
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Show var value depending on host
      debug:
        var: a_var_i_need
```

## Result

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/test/ playbook.yml 

PLAY [demonstrate host_vars usage] ********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show var value depending on host] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostA] => {
    "a_var_i_need": "var value for host A"
}
ok: [hostB] => {
    "a_var_i_need": "var value for host B"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************
hostA                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
hostB                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```